# creating the welcome page

Tags: jsp-tags

why is the user name not desplayed on the web page using the following code?

```
String custId = (String) session.getAttribute("customerId");
String emailId = (String) session.getAttribute("emailId");
String phoneNumber = (String) session.getAttribute("phoneNumber");
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="70%" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td align="center">Welcome to Going Green !</td>
</tr
```

Comment: Because there no instruction to render the username? And looking at your session it is even not in there...

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure that your sessions contain anything ?
- where do you place the string variables in the html code ?